# Scalable React Apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know a little about the scalability of React Apps:

What are the best practices that are usually used to manage and create scalable states in web applications with Reactjs? *

Comment: This is extremely broad. Do you have more specific concerns? Do you feel like you're doing a specific practice that won't scale well? Are you wanting to learn more about overall designing a project structure that scales well? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very popular and efficient way to manage states in large applications or states that are somehow "big" is using [react/redux](https://react-redux.js.org) library. It's already used in JS Vanilla for the same purpose and it's been built for react as well.
Another option is the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) from React.JS itself. It manages large states and scalable/large applications so we don't have to pass down states thru props over and over and over.